# React Native Typescript: Use functions inside interface and in components

Tags: typescript, interface, react-typescript

how can i use function declared in interface inside FunctionComponent

```
interface IProps {
  someFunction(): Promise<boolean>;
}

const SomeClass: FC<IProps> = props => {
// Want to use somefunction method here how can i use this?? 
}
```

Also how can i call someFunction() from other component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of React component as a function which accepts some parameters.
For example you can write a function which accepts another function:

```
function logName(getName: () => string) {
   const name: boolean = getName();
   console.log(name);
}
```

And then you can call `logName` with *any* function which returns name, for example you can write:

```js
function getEnglishName() { return "John Doe"; }
function getRussianName() { return "Ivan Ivan"; }

logName(getEnglishName); // logs "John Doe" to console
logName(getRussianName); // logs "Ivan Ivan" to console
```

Notice how, when we *called* `logName`, we did not do `logName(getEnglishName())` but we did `logName(getEnglishName)`. That's because `getEnglishName` is a _function returning string, when it is called`, but` getEnglishName` is simply a string!

Similarly to the above, React function components are just functions which accept *something* and return react components.

Now, what React function accepts is commonly called "props". But you can simply think of it as argument to a function.

So, in order to write a react component you have to define a function which accepts "something". In your case, that "something" is `someFunction` from `IProps` interface. However, it would be the **caller** which should give the real value of `someFunction` to your  React component.

First of all, you better use slightly different notation for `IProps`.

```
interface IProps {
    someFunction: () => Promise<boolean>;
}
```

Then, I assume that you did `import {FC} from 'react'`, and then you just can do what's below

```js
const FunctionComponent: FC<IProps> = props => {
  // This accesses "someFunction"
  props.someFunction
}
```

Since `props` object will contain everything you define in `IProps`, just like a regular object of type `IProps`

Actually, since you have a `Promise` type, which means that `someFunction` is *asynchronous*, the proper full form would be

```
const FunctionComponent: FC<IProps> = async props => {
  // This accesses "someFunction"
  const resultBoolean: boolean = await props.someFunction();
}
```

Now, somebody may **use** your component like this:

```
// another file
async function returnsBoolean(){
    return true; // return right away
}


// {} below means AnotherComponent needs no arguments
const AnotherComponent: React.FC<{}>= () => {
   return ( <FunctionComponent someFunction={returnsBoolean} />);
}
```

Comment: @Shwetadodiya if that works for you please mark the answer as accepted! Happy to help more or edit, if we need  more clarity around what I wrote

Comment: Where should i write code inside someFunction()?  const resultBoolean: boolean = await props.someFunction() {}; something like this ?

Comment: so_close - That works for me. Thank you. mark you answer as accepted

Comment: I am getting this error : Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)

Comment: I updated answer to include explanation together with a short example. Let me know if that's better for you. If you just start learning React and JS, I suggest you go with something simple than passing functions, like maybe try to pass values first and see how that goes. Also, if you do not know typescript (it's that JS extension which adds types), learn javascript first. It will make life easier for some time. Hard to learn many things at once